# Is there a way to upload a file on Appium/Selenium node when using WindowsDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, grid, appium

As searches on the web show, it should be quite easy and it is indeed if you are using ChromeDriver. You are basically adding the

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

line and it's transferring files/completing the path for you. But I'm having no luck trying to get something similar working with the WindowsDriver for Appium. Is there any possible way to transfer a file to a node? I'm quite out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0):

File upload can be done via sikuli library in java

```
Pattern fileNameInput = new Pattern("D:\Selenium\FileOpenInput.PNG");
Pattern openButton = new Pattern("D:\Selenium\OpenButton.PNG");
Screen screen = new Screen();
screen.type(fileNameInput, "D:\Selenium\OpenButton.PNG");
screen.click(openButton);
```

http://automationtesting.in/file-upload-using-sikuli-in-selenium/

Comment: Jayanth Bala, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)